# How to reload mapping for Hibernate validation?

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation

```
    constraintMapping = new ConstraintMapping();
    configuration = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class).configure();
    configuration.addMapping(constraintMapping);
    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = configuration.buildValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
```

Looks like mapping is being copied during the process of `Factory` creation, and any changes in mapping after it have no effect. I want be able add new constraints to the mapping after `Validator` is created. Is there a way to reload it? Or creating new `ValidatorFactory` is the only way to have changes take effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to dynamically reload the data. You would have to rebuild the `ValidatorFactory`. This ties in with [HV-98](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-98) which discusses a dynamic metadata reload feature.